# How did Raphael paint halos?

Tags: religion, art, renaissance, painting

Yesterday, I had the pleasure of seeing [Raphael's cartoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raphael_Cartoons) "Christ's Charge to Peter":

[image: Image of Raphael's "Christ's Charge to Peter"]

In it, Christ and the apostles are depicted with halos that appear to be perfect [ellipses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse).

[image: Enlarged image of halo]

I only know of one method to draw an ellipse ([involving two pins and a loop of string](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JvciWGTdBq8)), but a naive application of this method punctures the paper with the pins. So how did Raphael paint his halos?

Comment: One could use the naive method to create a stencil (I think this is the correct word) and use the stencil on the picture.

Comment: ...or perhaps the artist just practiced and got really good at drawing elipses freehand?

Comment: See also the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trammel_of_Archimedes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A article [here](https://www.vox.com/2015/6/15/8774475/renaissance-art-tracing-cartoons) discusses some of the techniques used by artists of the era, and the probable answer is that sketches were made separately and then transferred onto the main work-essentially tracing from the sketch.

The linked article points to a video by the Getty Museum [Almost Invisible: The Cartoon Transfer Process](https://youtu.be/46_wiOboDk4) which goes into detail on some of the possible processes involved, including the [creation of a 'carbon copy'](https://youtu.be/46_wiOboDk4?t=67) using a stylus tracing an original with a layer of charcoal or chalk coated paper in between.

Another video, [Raphael's technique](https://youtu.be/qCwPtt-QWoc) goes into detail specifically concerning a different transfer method done by [piercing the original sketch](https://youtu.be/qCwPtt-QWoc?t=417) and then dabbing a charcoal powder through the holes, and then 'connecting the dots'.

Any of these methods would allow the creation of the halos by whatever method being used to create them, and then transferring that sketch onto the final product, without any apparent pin holes.

(One other technique I am aware of for creating an ellipse involves casting a shadow of a circular object (for instance a plate) held at an angle to the light source, then tracing that shadow.)

Comment: In keeping with a comment above, I will add that, when in Freshman Drawing in art school many years ago, we took a square of paper, scribed a circle on it using a compass, and then spent **two weeks** drawing that in perspective, freehand